# using shell_exec with a command with a pipe ( | )

Tags: php, linux

Hi i have a Linux command what uses a pipe to obtain its result. It basically search a pdf for a string and returns the page numbers of all of the occurrences.

```
pdftotext /var/www/html/custom/test.pdf - | awk -vRS=$'\\f' -vNAME='06/1133/13' \ 'index($0,NAME){printf \"%d,\", NR}'
```

The result of this on the command line looks like this:

```
8,9,10,11,
```

Trying to run this in php with this code

```
  $command = "pdftotext /var/www/html/custom/test.pdf - | awk -vRS=$'\\f' -vNAME='06/1133/13' \ 'index($0,NAME){printf \"%d,\", NR}'";
echo shell_exec($command);
```

i get the following output

```
1,
```

I have used the php script to print out the command variable to make sure the formatting is correct. I can run the output command on the terminal and this works with out issue.

What is needed within the PHP script to allow this to run?

Comment: Have you tried using `escapeshellcmd()` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, but that changed the command to `pdftotext /var/www/html/custom/test.pdf - \| awk -vRS=\$'\\f' -vNAME='06/1133/13' \\ 'index\(\$0,NAME\)\{printf \"%d,\", NR\}''` and won't run.

Comment: Can u link/add the test.pdf

Comment: @Oli, unfortunately not as it is full of customers data. I have found this PDF, same issue, so when running this within linux

`pdftotext /var/www/html/custom/test1.pdf - | awk -vRS=$'\f' -vNAME='motherboard' \ 'index($0,NAME){printf "%d,", NR}' `

I get the result `2,3,4,5,7,`

when running this in php (on the same server) 

`echo shell_exec(pdftotext /var/www/html/custom/test1.pdf - | awk -vRS=$'\\f' -vNAME='motherboard' \ 'index($0,NAME){printf \"%d,\", NR}'");`

I get this, `1,`

test1.php [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccxjuuebqxcjjdy/test1.pdf?dl=1)

Comment: The pipe is not the issue, I think it's something with the backslash or quotes..For example, this works fine: $content = \`pdftotext ./test1.pdf - | grep motherboard | grep BIOS\`; (the backticks surrounding the string are the same as calling exec(string))

Comment: I solved this by moving the command in to a bash file and then have PHP call that with variables.  so the php command is very simple.